# How to cover Junit test cases for FutureCallback<HttpResponse> completed, failed and canceled api in below code

Tags: java, junit, testcase

CloseableHttpAsyncClient execute() method is working with FutureCallback,is there any way to write unit testing for that response, I have to increase the coverage but I am unable to cover for FutureCallback completed, failed and canceled api in below code.

```
@Service
public class SplunkLogger {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SplunkLogger.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient;     

    private void log(SplunkMessage splunkMessage) {
        String messageStr = new Gson
                ().toJson(splunkMessage);
        logger.info(messageStr);
           if(this.environment.getActiveProfiles()[0].contains("local")){
            return;
        }
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        post.addHeader(Constants.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, Constants.SPLUNK_TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
        post.addHeader(Constants.CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, Constants.CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE_HEADER);
        SplunkRequest request = SplunkRequest.builder().event(messageStr).build();
        try {
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(request)));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        httpClient.start();
        httpClient.execute(post, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void completed(HttpResponse httpResponse) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Request completed: " + IOUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void failed(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Request failed: " + e);
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelled() {
                System.out.println("Request failed: ");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to cover here exactly? The code that runs inside of the `FutureCallback<>` class?

Comment: Yes Dawid, I am trying to cover the code inside future callback
cancelled(). failed(Exception e) and completed(HttpResponse httpResponse) part

Comment: Do you want to cover checking whether that code just printed out the right text?

Comment: Yes,I am looking for same

Comment: If you want to *unit* test something, turn it into an actual unit. So extract your future callback into a separate class, and you can unit test it as much as you want. (But, right now there isn’t much interesting behavior to test in your future callback)